# How to get a specific details of some id when i click the hyperlink id using PHP and SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, database

I created a table that contains Student id etc. Then i fetch all the database data into the table, while making the hyperlink of the Student ID's row. So the problem is i wanted to show the clicked Student ID specifically at the new page with its own details. I found a few ways to do it but it is in mysql, i do it using sqlsrv.
 This is my code.

```
$sql = 'select * from StudentAttn order by Dates';
$params = array();
$options =  array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET);
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql , $params, $options );
```

This is my fetch

```
if ($num_rows > 0){

while ( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
echo "<tbody style='border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; background-color: white'><tr>"
        . "<td align='center' for='Student_ID'>" . "<a href='http://localhost:8080/myschool/Studentdetail.php>" .$row['Student_ID']."</a>"."</td>"
```

This is the next page

```
$sql1 = 'select * from StudentAttn where Student_ID = "'.$_SESSION['Student_ID'].'" ';
```

Sorry for these mess up. I am new here.

Comment: I suggested use query string in the URL,like as "<a href='http://localhost:8080/myschool/Studentdetail.php?sid=23'>

Comment: @kannan not working. but thanks

Answer (score 0):

DO this: Pass your data in query string then fetch it using $_GET in second page:

```
while ( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
echo "<tbody style='border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; background-color: white'><tr>"
        . "<td align='center' for='Student_ID'>" . "<a href='http://localhost:8080/myschool/Studentdetail.php?Student_ID=".$row['Student_ID'].">" .$row['Student_ID']."</a>"."</td>";
```

the next page

```
$sql1 = 'select * from StudentAttn where Student_ID = "'.$_GET['Student_ID'].'" ';
```

Comment: Error : sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Comment: if your id is `int` then remove single quotes from where